# Use Java 8 stream to convert enum to set

Tags: java-8, stream

I have an enum looks like:

```
public enum Movies {
SCIFI_MOVIE("SCIFI_MOVIE", 1, "Scifi movie type"),
COMEDY_MOVIE("COMEDY_MOVIE", 2, "Comedy movie type");

private String type;
private int id;
private String name;

Movies(String type, int id, String name) {
    this.type = type;
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
```

}

I know that I can use stream to create a Set of Movies `enum` with:

```
Set<Movie> Movie_SET = Arrays.stream(Movie.values()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

What if I want to create a Set of enum Movies id. Is there a way to do that with stream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are able to get stream of `Enum` values then rest could easily be achieved.

You could use `custom Collector impl` (My favorite of all time), see example below of a custom collector:-

```
 Set<Integer> movieIds = Arrays
                .stream(Movies.values())
                .collect(
                         HashSet::new,
                         (set, e) -> set.add(e.getId()),
                         HashSet::addAll
                );
```

Or you could use `map` to fetch ids only and the `collect` to collect these ids to a Set as usual.

```
Set<Integer> movieIds = Arrays
                        .stream(Movies.values())
                        .map(Movies::getId)
                        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use EnumSet implementation for this purpose e.g.

For obtaining the Set of Movies:

```
Set<Movies> movies = EnumSet.allOf(Movies.class);
```

For obtaining only movies ids:

```
Set<Integer> moviesIds = movies.stream().map(Movies::getId).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, assuming you have a getter for your id, your Movies enum might look like this:

```
public enum Movies {
    SCIFI_MOVIE("SCIFI_MOVIE", 1, "Scifi movie type"),
    COMEDY_MOVIE("COMEDY_MOVIE", 2, "Comedy movie type");

    private String type;
    private int id;
    private String name;

    Movies(String type, int id, String name) {
        this.type = type;
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Then, you can get the set of ids by using `Stream.map()`:

```
Set<Integer> movieIds = Arrays.stream(Movies.values()).map(Movies::getId)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

BTW, an alternative way to create the set of all movies is to use `EnumSet.allOf()`:

```
Set<Integer> movieIds = EnumSet.allOf(Movies.class).stream().map(Movies::getId)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: `EnumSet.allOf()` is really nice to use. Thanks!